# fetching database records using ajax polling

Tags: php, mysql

am am thinking of polling using ajax with a rate of 5 sec so that i get all updates before  5 sec from 
now with out losing any updates .is there a chance that i will miss out some data due to network latency or some other issue. can anyone suggest an method so that  I get records if any UPDATE is made within 5 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send the ID (or insert date) of the last item you've got with previous update you can fetch the newer records from the database and you won't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the total number of rows as parameter and check using that.

You can also check by sending the last id as parameter.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea. Consider the following scenario:
1. You fetch some rows.
2. Set the last id in the session.
3. Send the data to the client.
4. Something goes wrong and a client never gets the data.
You will miss some data this way.